# Transaction won't confirm

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Hoping someone can help me! I'm pretty new to all this.

I sent a payment about 12 hours ago, but it's still marked as 0 confirmed. I was fairly sure the address I sent it to was correct, but it won't send and I'm a bit lost as to what to do.

Is anyone able to shed some light on it? There's a transaction fee included so didn't think I'd be put on the bottom of the pile.

Transaction ID is: 12c3cfa1ecdfbed226c8d2f48767ff7e6845d31850eaae6ea8ad31977521ca1e-000

Comment: The fee is really low, so it is going to take a long time to confirm. What wallet did you use to send that? Fee calculation is off.

Answer (score 0):

Just wait, it will eventually confirm. When I process large transactions they usually take hours to confirm. Smaller transactions usually go through quicker. There is a lot of randomness involved in the confirmation process and it might also have to do with the wallet you are using.

So don't worry, your transaction will eventually be confirmed.

Comment: You cannot guarantee that all you need to do, in general, is wait. If a transaction doesn't pay enough fees, it might be that miners just won't ever process it.

Comment: You are correct. There is a fee included in the transaction but I see now that it is really small.

Comment: I'm using bitcoin-qt and just used the recommended fee. I'd have paid more if I knew! Guessing no way to add more on now. What happens if its never processed? Anyway to get it back? I found someone said about using bitcoind and running a command but I'm on os x and couldn't get it working just yet

Comment: As Adriaan Said, just wait, it will be confirmed as soon as be included in a block